# Can the DisplayName attribute be accessed without using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, reflection, extension-methods

I have refactored out a generic CSV builder for List using lambda expressions to access the correct values

```
public static string ToCsv<TModel>(this List<TModel> list, string delimiter, string lineBreak, string valueWrap, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] expressions)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();

  var headers = expressions.Select(m => String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", valueWrap, GetPropertyName(m))).ToArray();
  sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", String.Join(delimiter, headers), lineBreak));

  foreach (var listItem in list)
  {
    var values = expressions.Select(m => String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", valueWrap, m.Compile()(listItem))).ToArray();
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", String.Join(delimiter, values), lineBreak));
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

This works well, however because I am trying to move this into some common code for several projects across several servers to access. I cannot reference the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly

Is there a good way to access the `DisplayName` Attribute and if that doesnot exist, access the variable name?

My current attempt access the `((MemberExpression) expression.Body).Member.Name` however it will not work if it has to convert a value to string. (ie passing an int and implicitly converting)

A second attempt of iterating over the attributes did not work for inner class (ie `model` => `model.innerClass.property`)

Comment: Further Info: After having no solution, I went ahead and used the `System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper` however I have ran into another issue.  Without the HtmlHelper and its ViewData, It will not get the DisplayName Attribute of a property.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple simple helper functions, you can eliminate all reference to the System.Web.Mvc assembly.  You'll also notice in the example below that (model => model.member.property) works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Class1> foobars = new List<Class1>();
            foobars.Add(new Class1 { Foo = "Hello world!", Bar = -1, Skip = false, Ref = new Class2 { ToBe = true } });

            string result = foobars.ToCsv(",", Environment.NewLine, "\"", m => m.Foo, m => m.Bar, m => m.Ref.ToBe);
        }

        public class Class1
        {
            [DisplayName("Foo Property")]
            public string Foo { get; set; }

            public int Bar { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Skipped Property")]
            public bool Skip { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Reference")]
            public Class2 Ref { get; set; }
        }

        public class Class2
        {
            [DisplayName("To Be or Not To Be")]
            public bool ToBe { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ToCsv<TModel>(this List<TModel> list, string delimiter, string lineBreak, string valueWrap, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] expressions)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var headers = expressions.Select(m => String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", valueWrap, GetDisplayName(m))).ToArray();
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", String.Join(delimiter, headers), lineBreak));

            foreach (var listItem in list)
            {
                var values = expressions.Select(m => String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", valueWrap, m.Compile()(listItem))).ToArray();
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", String.Join(delimiter, values), lineBreak));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        // Get DisplayName, otherwise fallback to Name
        private static string GetDisplayName(LambdaExpression memberReference)
        {
            MemberInfo info = GetMemberInfo(memberReference);
            DisplayNameAttribute displayNameAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(info, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
            return (displayNameAttr != null ? displayNameAttr.DisplayName : info.Name);
        }

        // Can be swapped for your favourite GetMemberInfo/GetPropertyInfo utility method (there are many out there)
        // Source: http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/extension-methods-for-converting-lambda-expression-to-strings
        private static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(LambdaExpression memberReference)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpression;
            var unary = memberReference.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unary != null)
                //In this case the return type of the property was not object,
                //so .Net wrapped the expression inside of a unary Convert()
                //expression that casts it to type object. In this case, the
                //Operand of the Convert expression has the original expression.
                memberExpression = unary.Operand as MemberExpression;
            else
                //when the property is of type object the body itself is the
                //correct expression
                memberExpression = memberReference.Body as MemberExpression;

            if (memberExpression == null || !(memberExpression.Member is MemberInfo))
                throw new ArgumentException("Expression was not of the form 'x => x.member'.");

            return memberExpression.Member;
        }
    }
}
```